# crypto verifier.verify() always returns false - javascript

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I am trying to use the cypto verifier.verify to verify an RSA signature with my public key. When I do it on openssl, the verification returns as verified OK,
but when I do it in my program, verifier.verify always returns false.
This is the openssl command I tested to ensure that there is no problem with my signature or public key.

openSSL> dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature sign.txt.sha256 sign.txt
Verified OK

```
event is the signature that is passed in: "AIcrnumIAYQ6GegOIQzUlz9FS/uIiVlprXQyp8SFTtEEq4B/xv4flufsf35RS5Ki
ajUgAGWnmQ1gdXVNAV3Hpidip2EXTrHyfNF8MCGhueCgKPNML9fA+pW0K8RLTDUK
6V8/41fwQ+d/k6LjErenoa8sXFC3qRAg3w6xzmrtfLnHqjYW86kRVo4fCzAOeHse
a4jtJ9+EDjJfwB4vnP4eMF/QlrRvc1+U4aVB3nEtPb/l8/c5W70NWGz3JOrpENum
E7GnjwSk6bOysDQxCQ1z+AF4fv/VqmBizF4LFk+NbyYM8Z4T/cMlz0bU4VNJBlf5
k526esT9Mj4Eo93y+fW+cA=="

    const crypto = require('crypto');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var expired = false;


    const pub = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApnVi9xDUe6+Kimb2TniZ\nX/pBGIhy5glXpHYgGmTOeYQa45bDkdwn3ydk15M/K7xpwJsHWSM2K2cQzCO7YCu8\nrgEMHggezt69KtXt78ohNy7AwD2Vheo6uXfaR91X9bc2dZ9oR2pEWHh3MX5jXA9y\nRopDfA/xdWj8ZiZK0RPGzyGufRauhFUaf48+2emr0nwluAfl5v1fV7vm/sBxitbj\nwl7rmka6SYodhMPRnMphFbv66sN50fPcZop8kWHp+LcvXB0TIhccRvnPHkTqjc7/\nbGiGQly6cL7JkQrDbcDCuGqPc397qDHb2ABpyZKWCHpkVAwNyc5Y1uOjaSJgPwq6\n8QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n';

    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // from site https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6938
    //data is signed string that's passed into this in an above not shown function wrapper.
        try{
        //var message = new Buffer(event);   
        var message = event //needs to be just string apparently
        var verifier = crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA256");
        console.log("message " + message);   
        //verifier.update takes in the string that was signed.
        verifier.update(message); //was data

        //verifier.verify
        //pub is a string of public signature in PEM format
        //signature is the base64 binary encoded version of data
        //base64 tells the format so it can be verified
        //expired is a bool, for this example, hard coded above to false, you'll want to check that for real.

        //console.log('vf: ', verifier.verify(pub, message, 'base64'));


        callback(null, {
            verified: (verifier.verify(pub, message, 'base64'))
        });
        } catch (e) {
        callback("Bad Request: " + e);
        }
    };
```

Comment: A failed signature verification can mean any number of things: wrong key, wrong encoding, incomplete/overfull ciphertext. You should show the signing code and give the example values that you've used. Otherwise, it would be plain guessing what might be wrong with this code (or the signing code). In short, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Its not the wrong key, since I checked that my public key is correct with the openssl verification. This also proves that the signature is correct. i have also added example values I used

Comment: I checked that the public key I am using and the private key to generate the signature are correct by running the openssl verification command. I have added the example value I used for the signature that I want to verify that returns false in my function but true in openssl

I was thinking that maybe my signature needed to be in different format  and changed it to base64 but that also didnt work.

Comment: How does the data look? If it is not a valid UTF-8 encoded string, this will obviously be wrong. See: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_verifier_update_data_input_encoding

Comment: If my data, the signature is just a string as shown, is it not already UTF-8 encoded? Or does it need be encoded some way?

Comment: Don't show your data. You're just showing the file name. I don't see how it is read. It is possible that your data is a valid UTF-8 string in which case, this should work as expected, but you should know that cryptographic operation don't work on strings, but on bytes. That is why you should use a Buffer.

Comment: I went back and looked at what data is - I inserted the string I did the signing on and it worked - thanks so much :)